# Choose input validation based on selection in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation, pug

I'm trying to setup validation on a field based on which option a user chooses from a dropdown. If they choose 'email' I run email validation on the input field. If they choose 'user' I run number validation on the field. I would like to use `ng-if` on each of these possible input fields and choose which one to show based on the value selected from the dropdown, but I can't seem to figure out how to best determine which option they chose. Current Jade code below:

```
td
  div.btn-group
    button.btn.btn-primary(data-toggle='dropdown' ng-model='type')#type Type
    button.btn.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary(data-toggle='dropdown')
      span.caret
    ul.dropdown-menu(role='menu')#list
      - for (var x in listTypes)
        li
          a(class='list-type' data-list-type-uri='#{x}' data-list-type='#{listTypes[x].name}')= listTypes[x].name
td
  input.form-control(name='listType' id='list', type='text', placeholder='List Type' ng-model='email' validator='email' required message-id='email')
  span(id='email' ng-hide='!email.length')
  input.form-control(name='listType' id='list', type='text', placeholder='List Type' ng-model='user' validator='number' required message-id='number')
  span(id='number' ng-hide='!number.length')
```

Answer (score 0):

use the required attribute with input type submit